# Keep edge loops in triangle face?

Tags: faces, edges, topology, geometry

Look at this picture, I have to fill the empty vertices.

[image]

The shape the face I have to fill is triangle. I can't keep edge loops after adding triangle faces, is there a way to avoid using triangle in this situation and keep edge loops work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this can split triangle into quads, just cut it with *Knife tool* <kbd>K</kbd>. But geometry will become densier in this place.

P.S. Also, I want to mention that if you are doubting how to subdivide something to quads - use *Subsurf Modifier* set to *Simple* mode (*Simple* - because we need to keep original curvature without smoothing). This is easy and absolutely non-destructive way to see how it can be done. So, add modifier and set viewport shading to wireframe <kbd>Z</kbd> and don't forget to enable *Draw all edges* in object settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is really hard make triangle to quad everytime.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but, just curious... why not, say, just the leftmost of the yellow line segments?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you are asking. What do you want to do with the leftmost part?

Comment: Perhaps @RobinBetts is suggesting that only the left most cut is needed to create a quad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5p9a.png

Comment: @RayMairlot   Yup, that was it... but Serge may have good reasons not to do that.

Comment: We can go even further and forget about yellow line, but instead fill triangle and dissolve top left edge https://i.imgur.com/ToQGrqN.png
Thing is - I don't know what OP will do next, maybe extrude something, so better keep his original work untouched.